# Change variable between parentheses

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    b = 1.860572
    if "%b" in line and "4.871899" in line and "1.995131" in line:
        m.write("match" + "\n")
```

I would like to have the `b` variable in the place where I now have `'%b'`, so its just like the other two numbers, but without hard coding it. Anybody knows how to do this? I'm still learning Python.

Comment: What do you mean by `hard coding it`?

Comment: @GáborErdős: He means without actually doing `if "1.860572" in line ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if str(b) in line and "4.871899" in line and "1.995131" in line:
```

Incidentally, it is slightly inefficient to have an assignment inside a `for` loop that doesn't change based on the thing being iterated over. Depending on your use case, it may make more sense to do:

```
b = 1.860572
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if str(b) in line and "4.871899" in line and "1.995131" in line:
        m.write("match" + "\n")
```

Or

```
b = "1.860572"
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if b in line and "4.871899" in line and "1.995131" in line:
        m.write("match" + "\n")
```

Or

```
b = 1.860572
b_s = str(b)
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if b_s in line and "4.871899" in line and "1.995131" in line:
        m.write("match" + "\n")
```

---

One more thing to watch out for: converting a float to a string doesn't always give you the same literal value you used to create the float in the first place.

```
>>> b = 1.9999999999999999
>>> s ="1.9999999999999999"
>>> str(b) in s
False
>>> str(b) in "abc2.0def"
True
>>> str(b)
'2.0'
```

This is because `str` is designed to return a readable string, not necessarily something perfectly representative of the object's data. For floats, this means `str()` might round to fewer decimal places than you originally specified. So if you're searching through a file for a precise sequence of digits, it may make sense to create `b` as a string in the first place, so there's no loss of precision.